# How to configure redirects Glassfish4 Maven Webapp

Tags: angularjs, maven, glassfish, angular-routing

I am developing a WebApp using Glassfish 4. I have a REST backend, developed in JAVA using Jersey, and a AngularJS frontend. All this is contained in a MAVEN Jersey-Quickstart-Webapp.

Now, the problem I have is that when people query the URL for my app:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/
```

It works fine, and sends the appropriate index.html to the user. However, if the user types a URL that 'should' be handled by my Apps routing, say like:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/search
```

it gives a 404 error. However, this URL can be reached from within in the app if you start from the /MyApp/ route, because the index.html that is served with all the angularJS stuff is able to understand and control the routing.

Essentially the problem I face is that I need to set up the appropriate redirects for all the necessary places that should return the index.html.

So, when I hit any of the following URLs it should send the user the index.html, and let AngularJs figure out the routing

Eg.

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/search   ----> index.html
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/results  ----> index.html
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/browse   ----> index.html
```

Unfortunately, I am probably being really thick here, but I don't know how to configure the server/webapp to do this. How do I go about doing this? I assume it is fairly obvious/trivial, but I'm pretty new to all this stuff, so go easy on me!

**EDIT 1:** I've had some good help about using a mod-rewrite or the UrlRewriteFilter but neither of these seems to work for Glassfish4 as far as I can see. Is there an equivalent out there for these that somebody might know of?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It sounds like you need an Apache up-front to rewrite your URLs? How is that related to Maven?

Comment: It may not be related to Maven - I'm not sure where this is configured, so I included Maven as a tag.

Comment: Did you remove the hash "#" that angular use for his routing ?

Answer (score 2):

- Log into glassfish In the Admin Console, expand the Configurations
  node. Expand the server-config node. Ignore this step if you are
  running a developer domain (a domain that does not have clustering
  capability). Expand HTTP Service. Expand Virtual Servers. Click
  server. On the Edit Virtual Server page, click the Add Property
  button. In the Name column, type redirect_1.

  If you are using Application Server 9.0, type
  from=//myproduct1
  url-prefix=/mywarname/mypages/products/myproduct1.jsp in the Value
  column.

  Note - The value of the  you provide here needs to
  match the value of the context root specified in the web.xml or
  application.xml file.

Comment: That seems to be just for one page redirect I think.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Tunaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) says, you need use an apache and use the `mod_rewrite`.
also, you can use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) thats allows you to rewrite URLs before they get to your code.

For that, you need add to your maven file the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And add in your **WEB-INF/web.xml** file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, you have a big number of parameters specified in the documentation:
http://cdn.rawgit.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/master/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#filterparams

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/search   ----> search.html
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/results  ----> results.html
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/browse   ----> browse.html
```

Comment: Hi MrMins - that look like what I am looking for. I've just added those two pieces to my project, but it doesn't seem to work. Does UrlRewriteFilter work for glassfish?

Comment: @TomO'Brien no, it's working with `Apache Tomcat` you need configure your `Apache` to accepts and rewrite those URLs

Comment: @TomO'Brien read this thread to configure: [http://se7so.blogspot.com/2013/03/configuring-apache-http-server-along.html][1]


  [1]: http://se7so.blogspot.com/2013/03/configuring-apache-http-server-along.html

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. So this doesn't work with Glassfish then? In my logs when I have configure it like you say it gives this: ebModule[null] ServletContext.log():org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter INFO: loaded (conf ok)..... However, nothing happens when I hit the URLS only a 404.